# mysql: remove duplicated when joining three tables

Tags: mysql

I have three table typemaster,salaryaddition,salarydeduction

**typemaster** table

typeid  | typename |

1        |Act.Alw      |

2        |Canteen   |

3        |Sht.Alw     |

4        |L.O.P      |

**salaryaddition** table

slno |employee |salarytype | amount |

1      |1              |1               |200 |

**salarydeduction** table

employee | salarytype | amount |

1              |2                 |500 |

1              | 4                | 300 |

I want to display

employee | Addition | Amount | Deduction | Amount

1            | Act.Alw   |200        | Canteen      | 500    |

1            | null        | null        | L.O.P          | 300  |

I write query but it display duplicate result

```
select a.employee,a.typename,a.amount,b.typename,b.amount from
(select employee,typename,amount from salaryaddition 
 join typemaster on     typeid=salaryaddition.salarytype) a,
(select employee,typename,amount from salarydeduction 
 join typemaster on typeid=salarydeduction.salarytype) b
where a.employee=b.employee
```

Comment: do you have an employee table?

Comment: yes , employeemaster table contains employee,username

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have an employee table, you can try something like

```
SELECT  e.employee,
        sat.typename,
        SUM(sa.amount) amount,
        sdt.typename,
        SUM(sd.amount) amount
FROM    employeemaster e LEFT JOIN
        salaryaddition sa   ON  e.employee = sa.employee LEFT JOIN
        typemaster sat  ON  sa.salarytype = sat.typeid LEFT JOIN
        salarydeduction sd  ON  e.employee = sd.employee LEFT JOIN
        typemaster sdt  ON  sd.salarytype = sdt.typeid
GROUP BY    e.employee,
            sat.typename,
            sdt.typename
```

Comment: thanks , this query also give me dublicate.If salarydeduction contains more data than salaryaddition it display dublicate data from salaryaddition

Comment: Yes, that depends on the types you wish to display.

Comment: I modified the resulting table pls check. I want to display like that if salarydeduction contains more data than salaryaddition. This query give me Act.Alw | 200 in next row.